# How do I make my HTML5 logon portal require user input before logging in?

Tags: html, authentication, server

I am making a logon portal for my business. It is just a basic one with only HTML5. No JS or CSS. I want it so that way the text box is filled and then only will it allow you to logon. Yes, I do have the required syntax in the textbox lines. However the program is just letting you logon without typing anything in.

[Link to the site](https://robustpossiblepostscript.chaitanyakuraku.repl.co/)

I added the required command in the command line.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title> Login Page </title>  
<style>   
Body {  
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  background-color: #30aeb3;
  
}  
button {   
       background-color: #ffffff;   
       width: 100%;  
        color: orange;   
        padding: 15px;   
        margin: 10px 0px;   
        border: none;   
        cursor: pointer;   
         }   
 form {   
        border: 3px solid #ffffff;   
    }   
 input[type=text ], input[type=password] {   
        width: 100%;   
        margin: 8px 0;  
        padding: 12px 20px;   
        display: inline-block;   
        border: 2px solid green;   
        box-sizing: border-box;   
    }  
 button:hover {   
        opacity: 0.7;   
    }   
  .cancelbtn {   
        width: auto;   
        padding: 10px 18px;  
        margin: 10px 5px;  
    }   
        
     
 .container {   
        padding: 25px;   
        background-color: lightblue;  
    }   
</style>   
</head>    
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;"> Logon Utility </h1>
 <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required >

      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="https://lovableignorantparticle.chaitanyakuraku.repl.co/">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Logon?</button>
        </a>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no `<form>` tag and your login button is an anchor. Also note that you cant put a button in an anchor

Answer (score -1):

Add a `form` to make the `required` work.

```css
Body {  
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  background-color: #30aeb3;
  
}  
button {   
       background-color: #ffffff;   
       width: 100%;  
        color: orange;   
        padding: 15px;   
        margin: 10px 0px;   
        border: none;   
        cursor: pointer;   
         }   
 form {   
        border: 3px solid #ffffff;   
    }   
 input[type=text ], input[type=password] {   
        width: 100%;   
        margin: 8px 0;  
        padding: 12px 20px;   
        display: inline-block;   
        border: 2px solid green;   
        box-sizing: border-box;   
    }  
 button:hover {   
        opacity: 0.7;   
    }   
  .cancelbtn {   
        width: auto;   
        padding: 10px 18px;  
        margin: 10px 5px;  
    }   
        
     
 .container {   
        padding: 25px;   
        background-color: lightblue;  
    }
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Logon Utility </h1>
 <form>
 <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required >

      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="https://lovableignorantparticle.chaitanyakuraku.repl.co/">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Logon?</button>
        </a>

    </div>
</form>
```